# How can I tell if barman is receiving the WAL stream during the day?

Tags: postgresql, barman

I followed the directions in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-restore-and-migrate-postgresql-databases-with-barman-on-centos-7) and [this](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.2/).  I've also successfully backed up from one server and restored it to another server. My barman is on a dedicated machine.  Looking good. But how can I tell if it's receiving the WAL stream during the day?

I can see the base backups in [barman-server]:/var/lib/barman

`barman check mydb` is reporting good things

```
[root@barman barman]# barman check mydb
Server mydb:
    PostgreSQL: OK
    is_superuser: OK
    PostgreSQL streaming: OK
    wal_level: OK
    replication slot: OK
    directories: OK
    retention policy settings: OK
    backup maximum age: OK (interval provided: 7 days, latest backup age: 24 minutes)
    compression settings: OK
    failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
    minimum redundancy requirements: OK (have 3 backups, expected at least 0)
    pg_basebackup: OK
    pg_basebackup compatible: OK
    pg_basebackup supports tablespaces mapping: OK
    pg_receivexlog: OK
    pg_receivexlog compatible: OK
    receive-wal running: OK
    archiver errors: OK
```

I have made a cron entry to run the `barman backup mydb` command (I think it makes more base backups)

```
[root@barman ~]# cat /etc/cron.d/do_backups 
30 23 * * * /usr/bin/barman backup mydb
```

[I share this guy's opinion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pgbarman/b9GFSb7fqVQ) that this doesn't belong in a separate cron job -- it belongs in the /etc/barman.d/.conf files as some kind of setting that says "Take a Base-Backup every X days" or some such, but that's not my problem in this question.

**How do I tell if this is receiving the WAL stream intra-day?**

- What do I look for to see some progress?
- Is there a way to see the IP address or a database connection for this so I know for sure?
- (I think I need a little education on WAL streams as well) Are WAL streams something that the PG server "sends" to barman? or is it "pulled" from a process on the barman?

Answer (score 0):

barman uses *cron* command to make sure WAL streaming actually works as expected

you can see related document [here](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.3/#cron)

this command runs every minute and added to your system cron if you have installed barman via debian/fedora packages

you can check it on debian here : `/etc/cron.d/barman`

for getting a sense about barman cron job , set log_level to DEBUG in `/etc/barman.conf`
and watch for barman log via `tailf /var/log/barman/barman.log`

every minute , this  command takes care of new WAL files and archive them